# Could not find the Qt platform plugin xcb, on Qt5 build from source on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, qt, debian, qt5

I build Qt5 on Debian 10 32 bits. Then I created a minimal Qt project, run `$ ~/qt/qt-everywhere-src-5.12.7/qtbase/bin/qmake project.pro` and `make`, but when I tried to execute the application I go the following:

What's going on?

```
$ ./release/project 
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in ""
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: linuxfb, minimal, offscreen, vnc, webgl.

Aborted
```

More info:

```
$ QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1 release/project 
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/home/user/qt/qt-everywhere-src-5.12.7/qtbase/plugins/platforms" ...
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/user/qt/qt-everywhere-src-5.12.7/qtbase/plugins/platforms/libqlinuxfb.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/user/qt/qt-everywhere-src-5.12.7/qtbase/plugins/platforms/libqlinuxfb.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "linuxfb"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QLinuxFbIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 330752
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("linuxfb")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/user/qt/qt-everywhere-src-5.12.7/qtbase/plugins/platforms/libqminimal.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/user/qt/qt-everywhere-src-5.12.7/qtbase/plugins/platforms/libqminimal.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "minimal"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QMinimalIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 330752
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("minimal")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/user/qt/qt-everywhere-src-5.12.7/qtbase/plugins/platforms/libqoffscreen.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/user/qt/qt-everywhere-src-5.12.7/qtbase/plugins/platforms/libqoffscreen.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "offscreen"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QOffscreenIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 330752
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("offscreen")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/user/qt/qt-everywhere-src-5.12.7/qtbase/plugins/platforms/libqvnc.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/user/qt/qt-everywhere-src-5.12.7/qtbase/plugins/platforms/libqvnc.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "vnc"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QVncIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 330752
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("vnc")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/user/qt/qt-everywhere-src-5.12.7/qtbase/plugins/platforms/libqwebgl.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/user/qt/qt-everywhere-src-5.12.7/qtbase/plugins/platforms/libqwebgl.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "webgl"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QWebGLIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 330752
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("webgl")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/home/user/QtProjects/project/release/platforms" ...
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in ""
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: linuxfb, minimal, offscreen, vnc, webgl.

Aborted
```

Comment: show the output of `QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1 ./release/project `

Comment: Just appended that info to the question. Looks like it's looking for `platforms` dir at executable path. Not sure what that means.

Comment: The plugins created by your Qt compilation must be in the `/home/user/QtProjects/project/release/platforms`  folder, and according to the log you show, it is only available for webgl. If you want to use X11 then you must use the `-qt-xcb` option when compiling the Qt source code. See https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/linux-requirements.html

Comment: Well, interesting, gonna compile it again so. Any comment on why Qt doesn't pick that by default while compiling?

Comment: Because that is the developer's task :-).

Comment: May I ask about the difference between `-xcb` and `-qt-xcb`?

Comment: Great, now it works. Would like to ask about the platforms folder though, is seems kind of too much work have to copy it to all Qt projects. Is there any work around this?

Answer (score 0):

`libqxcb.so` should be found in the `platforms` subdir of your application. if you want to change its searched location have a look at [qt.conf](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt-conf.html) ini file that controls plugins search path among other paths